# Trying to make a shirt design with 4000 max anchor points, but "Simplify" option is disabled

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, print-design, anchor-point

I'm new here, so excuse me for the noob questions.

I'm trying to make a shirt design like this shirt:

[image: Example Shirt]

It has to be SVG, using 2 different layers for each color (white and pink), and the max amount of anchor points per layer/color is 2000.

So I have my SVG file in Adobe Illustrator, with 2 layers, but the option Object > Path > Simplify is disabled... I have no experience with AI whatsoever, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Document Info is also not showing me the amount of anchor points that I have right now, so I can't check if I have more than what's allowed for the print shop that I want to have print the shirt.

Could you please help me out to make my design suitable for plot printing (on a website such as Spreadshirt)? Thanks!

Here's my PSD and SVG:

- [PSD File](http://www.webl.es/public/Shirt_Rosan_flat.psd)
- [SVG File](http://www.webl.es/public/Shirt_Rosan_flat.svg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design seems to be a bitmap. No need to convert it to SVG, a PNG bitmap is enough. The SVG file is a must, if you created your work as line-art and want it printed by the plotter.

Imported bitmap has no curves and their anchors in Illustrator. That's why no simplify is selectable.

Your image size is 11in x 10in and the resolution is 300dpi. If that's ok, merge the layers in PSD and save as PNG. Check afterwards that you really have the transparency intact and not replaced with a solid color.

Check the details for bitmap images:
https://help.spreadshirt.com/hc/en-us/articles/207945305-Optimizing-pixel-graphics-for-print

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get the shirt printed and it looks great!

Answer (score 1):

The way your image is at the moment, with that "distressed" look (all of the voids and hollows) in each letter, Will be nearly impossible for a plotter.  If you did an image trace in illustrator, converting the artwork from raster to vector, there would be no possible way you would have less than 2000 anchor points per color.

I went ahead and did the separations for you in Photoshop. View them in your channels panel. In my opinion, any screen printer that cannot produce transparencies for the screens from a separated Photoshop image, probably is not worth dealing with.  If you were to bring this attached file to any local screen printer, these separations should be all you would need.

[Shirt_Rosan_flat SEPS](https://mega.nz/#!28gz1arb!Y-iz5FLC-ywYKqyBP8AV64hjkWvtAWHsUJfEfXEEZLg)

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I was looking at the wrong instructions (for line art or something). It printed just fine using a regular PNG.